# Is it possible to extract contents of a symbol?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I want to make a dictionary mapping Strings to Symbols so that I can assign to objects a unique "t" property that always points to a unique symbol.

I can't figure out how to get the original string inside the symbol back out of the symbol so  that I can look up the Symbol table to check validity of the symbol.

Here's the sample code:

```
var t = {
    'Box': Symbol("Box")
};

var Box = (function() {
    var Box = function(x) {
        this.t = t['Box'];
        this.x = x;
    };

    return Box;
})();

var q = new Box(2);
console.log(q);
console.log(q.t);
```

I want to know if it is possible to get the string "Box" back out of the symbol Symbol(Box) without using regular expressions or creating a new structure which contains both the string "Box" and the Symbol "Box"(which is probably the best second solution).

Comment: What do you mean by "*so that I can look up the Symbol table to check validity of the symbol*", and why would you need the symbol's description for that? The entire point of symbols is not to use string comparisons but to rely on the identity of the symbol.

Comment: Suppose I identify the object using the symbol; I cannot use the Symbol as the key for my dictionary. Even if I know that foo.t is Symbol(Box), I cannot check if it is a Symbol(Box) from table 1, table 2, table 3, or from some table in an external script that happens to have a Box. To solve this, I need to get the symbol String, and look up my specific symbol table by that String that looks up "Box" and gives me my Symbol(Box), and I can compare this symbol to this specific Symbol(Box).

Comment: Of course you can use the symbol as the key for your dictionary - property keys don't have to be strings, they can be symbols as well. Alternatively, you could use an array, set, or map for your table. As I said, using a string for lookup defeats the entire purpose of the symbol, you could've stored the string in `.t` right away. If two modules use the same symbol description, they'd collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `for` and `keyFor` member in the `Symbol` Primitive
if you pass in a string into the `for` method it searches a global registory for that string, if it finds that the string has already been registered it retrieves the value of the string or else it registers the string
`keyFor` retrieves the value of the symbol. Passing an invalid argument to `keyFor` will throw an error >> `Symbol.keyFor(arg)` , arg must be a symbol
e.g

```
'use strict';
let myName = Symbol.for('victory');
console.log(Symbol.keyFor(myName));  // 'victory'
```

Your solution

```
var t = {
 'Box': Symbol.for("Box")
};

var Box = (function() {
  var Box = function(x) {
     this.t = t['Box'];
     this.x = x;
 };

  return Box;
})();

var q = new Box(2);
console.log(q);
console.log(Symbol.keyFor(q.t));
```

Comment: Wait, so Symbol.for creates a global symbol and Symbol.keyFor finds the global symbol, but both of them do not match against Symbol('blah')... Is that somehow more efficient than creating your own table mapping Strings to String, Symbol pairs? Because I'd like to avoid global symbols since I might want to use them in another context in the future, eg multiple symbol tables but one Symbol in one table not equal to symbol in another table.

Comment: @Dmitry `Symbol.for` just stores a symbol in the GlobalSymbolRegistry. I don't think that's much more efficient than implementing your own registry.

Comment: And is it always empty at start? Is there some way to traverse the Global Symbol Registry?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, GlobalSymbolRegistry is empty at the start. Note it's shared by all realms. It's only available via `for` and `keyFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regular expressions. A simple `slice` will work:

```js
console.log(Symbol("Box").toString().slice(7, -1)); // "Box"
```

That must work according to the spec:

> [**19.4.3.2 Symbol.prototype.toString ( )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring)
>
> 1. Let *s* be the **this** value.
> 2. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*s*) is Symbol, let *sym* be *s*.
> 3. Return [SymbolDescriptiveString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-symboldescriptivestring)(*sym*).
>
> [**19.4.3.2.1 Runtime Semantics: SymbolDescriptiveString ( *sym* )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-symboldescriptivestring)
>
> 2. Let *desc* be *sym*'s [[Description]] value.
> 3. If *desc* is **undefined**, let *desc* be the empty string.
> 4. Return the result of concatenating the strings `"Symbol("`, *desc*, and `")"`.

Comment: It still relies on a particular stringification format of the symbol; When I said regular expression, I implicitly meant any form of string manipulation. Nice to know that JS supports perl-like negative slicing for right offset though.

Comment: @Dmitry It relies on the stringification enforced by the spec. The spec does not provide any other way to read the [[Description]].